# Attribute errors after removing Anaconda & installing Python libraries directly

Tags: python, error-handling, attributes

May I request a help from you?

I recently removed Anaconda installation from my computer. And then I installed the free Python and its libraries – I have installed all libraries but I am getting errors when I try to use Keras, Tensorflow etc. libraries.

Very specific errors like:

1. partially initialized module 'fsspec' has no attribute 'utils' (most likely due to a circular import)
2. AttributeError: module 'snappy' has no attribute 'compress'

Would you think that the Anaconda de-installation wasn’t complete and something is causing the new libraries not to be able to function properly? Or should I de-install Python libraries and try to re-install them? I am just thinking that something needs to be cleaned up in the system.

Can you suggest something based on your experience on this?

Regards,
Rajat

Comment: What OS are you on? The answer here would be vastly different between Mac & Windows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.